error Failed to install the app. (Gradle problem in my react native project)
I am trying to learn react native so i setup my first project using a tutorial but cant get it to run in the emulator or anywhere i think.
when i run npm start and in another terminal npm run android it gives me an error saying could not download gradle 8.6-all.zip from gradle.org so i went to gradle.org to download it manually from the website and after saying thanks for downloading it never does download and shows this page
githubusercontent and does not load
so i downloaded gradle 8.6-all.zip manually from some tecent website and added it in my system variables and it was showing that i had gradle in my system but it then brought another error:
im new to stackoverflow so im not sure to show the error here is a picture just in case
the error im getting:
i tried some chatgpt solutions but nothing worked,
i tried something like this:
app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 --debug,
i also tried commenting the download from gradle.wrapper.properties but i dont think it worked either.
honestly i don't know what's going on.
thanks for reading, have a nice day.
